# dynamic dropdown button with dynamic values from list in flutter

Tags: flutter, list, datatable

I have DataTable in flutter, which is dynamically created. I have one column which is filled with dropdown buttons, I am facing this out of Range Error.

Here is the code

```
List<String> _values = [
    "m\u00b3",
    "ft\u00b3",
    "cm\u00b3",
    "m\u00b2",
    "ft\u00b2",
    "cm\u00b2",
    "kg",
    "lb",
    "ton",
    "No\'s",
  ];
  List<String> _selectedValues = [];
```

here is the initState

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _selectedValues = List.generate(_values.length, (index) => _values[0]);
  }
```

Here is the data cell in which I am creating it dynamically,

```
DataCell(
       Container(
                child: DropdownButton(
            value: _selectedValues[index],
            items: _values
                .map((value) => DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: value,
                      child: Text(value),
                    ))
                .toList(),
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _selectedValues[index] = value!;
              });
            },
          ),)),
```

Here is the Error I am Getting,

**Exception has occurred.
RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..9: 10)**

any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: how you are generating `DataCell`

Comment: What is `index` in `DataCell`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a List.genrate , so all the dropdown initial value would be different and also If you change value of one drop down it wont affect others

```
 List<String> _values = [
    "m\u00b3",
    "ft\u00b3",
    "cm\u00b3",
    "m\u00b2",
    "ft\u00b2",
    "cm\u00b2",
    "kg",
    "lb",
    "ton",
    "No\'s",
  ];
  List<String> _values2 = [
    "m\u00b3",
    "ft\u00b3",
    "cm\u00b3",
    "m\u00b2",
    "ft\u00b2",
    "cm\u00b2",
    "kg",
    "lb",
    "ton",
    "No\'s",
  ];
```

the code

```
List.generate(
      _values2.length,
      (index) => DataRow(
        cells: [
          DataCell(
            Container(
              child: DropdownButton(
                value: _values2[index],
                items: _values
                    .map((value) => DropdownMenuItem(
                          value: value,
                          child: Text(value),
                        ))
                    .toList(),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _values2[index] = value.toString();
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: but here is the problem, if i change it from LIST to only STRING, and let suppose i have 10 dropdown buttons generated dynamically, so if i change the value of one button, it will reflect in others as well and value of all the dropdown buttons will change

Comment: I edited my code , so if you change value of one button here it wont affect other dropdownvalues.